# Good ways to read a 16-bit code at very short distances (~0.5cm)

Tags: inductance, hall-effect

I'm looking at ways to read a 16-bit code over a very short distance, through an opaque material.

The sensors might be quite close to each other (~10cm), and they'll need to read only the code that is ~0.5cm from the sensor. The form factor should be compact. The stack would be the size of a AA battery or so, being inserted into the matching socket with up-to something like 10cm x 10cm x 10cm worth of space to hold the sensor (excluding the microcontroller and other components, they can be in an adjacent space).

Currently, I'm looking at using Hall Effect sensors to read a stack of 16 washers from the side; plastic representing 0, steel representing 1. A configuration of 16 sensors could read the stack at any time, or a configuration of two sensors could potentially read the stack when it is passed by the sensors.

Another approach I'm looking at is using an inductance sensor (like the [LDC1000](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/analog/dataconverters/inductance-to-digital-converter/index.html?DCMP=sva-psp-ssp-ldc1000-eu&HQS=sva-psp-ssp-ldc1000-pr-eu)) to measure the composition of the stack of washers.

Anyway, I'm wondering what other approaches are possible. RFID seems to be overkill and too expensive, but I am open-minded.

Comment: What are your constraints in terms of form factor, size, etc? RFID certainly seems like a good match here - 125KHz systems are cheap and not overly complicated.

Comment: @NickJohnson, I've updated the question to include some size and form constraints. Thanks. The 125KHz RFID seems reasonable  price-wise.

Comment: If RFID doesn't work, barcode scanners might. This is a common task, so I'd suggest avoiding proprietary solutions unless absolutely necessary; you'll let yourself in for a nightmare of development and debugging.

Comment: @NickJohnson I didn't mention that it has to be read through an opaque material. I've updated the description. Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking at a few 125KHz RFID modules. If I can find one that can read up to 16 tags at once that would be perfect.

Comment: Wait, reading multiple tags simultaneously is a requirement now? None of the other solutions you mentioned can do that either.

Comment: It would likely be a nice-to-have, but I'd rather explore the options without thinking about that.

Comment: Fair enough. FWIW, 125KHz tags don't support reading multiples; they're not smart enough for that.

Comment: Is the material opaque to IR?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by using reflective optical sensors. Black=0 and White/Silver=1 or vice a versa.

Comment: I didn't mention that it has to be read through an opaque material. I've updated the description. Thanks.